# Eudyptula Challenge List

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, eudyptula-challenge

I was interested in the [Eudyptula Challenges](http://eudyptula-challenge.org/) but I've just posted the solution to Task 1 and they are taking a huge time to respond. Can someone just post the Task List (Not the Solutions) so that I can do them at my own pace. Thanks in Advance :)

P.S I know that this is not exactly a programming question but didn't know where else to ask this.

Comment: In first mail from Eudyptula challenge you can see next: `Finally, if you have any questions about a task, or need help with
something, feel free to ask.  I'll alert my human that something is
going on, and they will get back to you in a few days with answers.`. So you should ask the creator of that challenge. Mailing tasks one by one can be done for a reason, and publishing all tasks here may break the whole point of that challenge.

Comment: The problem is they've taken a month and still haven't responded to my solution of Task 1. Hence no use to do them at their pace.

Comment: In my case it took them 2 days to respond to my mail. I'm pretty sure it's not a regular case you found yourself in. First of all, make sure you have configured your mail client correctly (AFAIR, it **must** be either Thunderbird or mutt). Secondly, inform the course owner about problem you are having (and probably ask him for the whole task set).

Comment: And it's 45 days since I submitted my 2nd task. Haven't gotten result yet.

Comment: Also: `If you are found to have posted your code publicly, or asked for help in
public locations, or copied code from public locations without properly
attributing it, or tried to cheat or fake challenge results in any way,
you will be removed from the challenge instantly. In short, do your own
work, and keep it to yourself.`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See here: https://github.com/agelastic/eudyptula

All tasks are in the README file. Try not to look at the solutions!

Comment: they don't seem to be taking any new people until the earlier people finish (which might be never). I guess the github repo is the only choice.